# Cannot Get Stripe Connect Account Balance

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have been trying to get balance for my connected accounts in stripe but whenever I make a api call it returns me platform's account balance instead of connected account balance. I am doing this in test mode.

```
const balance = await stripe.balance.retrieve({
    stripe_account: host.stripeAccountId,
  });
```

here "host" has a connected account linked with company's platform account.

Comment: Did you take a look at the API documentation? Linking/Quoting the stripe specific documentation could also direct other people to help you out in case you missed something. Best

Answer (score 0):

It should be `stripeAccount: 'acct_123'` not `stripe_account`. See the [API ref documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts?lang=node) for an example.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using that as well. Results were same